# Protecting direct access to port 11211 via a browser (memcached)

Tags: networking, domain, memcached, port

When I recently discovered about accessing ports via your browser at a domain level. Example, I accessed my domain at port 11211,  I got an output of this:

```
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
```

Is there any security precautions I need to consider taking into my server? How can I prevent users accessing at port 11211 but allowing my server to access to memcached? Is it a security concern of able to connecting via `domain.com:11211`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a server, you should close all your ports with a firewall, except those needed by the service.
If memcached is used in local, close the connection from outside. If the memcached is accessed from an other server, just open from this server and not from everywhere

Comment: I only use memcached in local, but exactly how do I close all ports and allow local services on the server use memcached?

Comment: Put a firewall on your server and ask it to close all the ports, except those needed by your service. On linux, look at iptables, on others, don't know

Answer (score 0):

Since memcache has no authentication implemented this is a big security concern.
Anyone can connect to your memcache server and read, delete, add or modify anything he wants.

Depending on your setup, configure your firewall accordingly (close all ports except the ones you need to be open) and/or let memcache bind only to localhost.